# How to use scala-time?

Tags: scala, sbt

somebody know scala-time? (https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time)
Have no idea how to use it. I can download it (on linux) and run sbt but theres always the same errormessage:

```
git clone git://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time
cd scala-time
sbt
Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.7.4 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4

    ==== local: tried

      /home/ll/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      /home/ll/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/jars/sbt_2.9.1.jar

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file:///home/ll/.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      file:///home/ll/.m2/repository/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/jars/sbt_2.9.1.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.jar

    ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.jar

    ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4!sbt_2.9.1.jar:

      http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.7.4/sbt_2.9.1-0.7.4.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

huh? Any other options?

Comment: Do you really want to *build* it (or toy with the source code) or do you just want to *use* it?

Answer (score 14):

To actually *use* it (as compared to building scala-time yourself), just add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.time" % "time_2.9.1" % "0.5"
```

to the `build.sbt` of the project you want to use it in.

**Addition**:

[Current versions](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time) may want to use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-time" % "0.6"
```

Comment: Hi. I cant find my build.sbt - im working with intellij and have a scala project, but in the project folder there is no build.sbt :(

Answer (score 5):

This is an sbt version problem, and you might be able to work around it by using a different sbt-launch or by changing the build a bit.  I get a similar error if I use sbt-launch-0.10.1.jar for this code, but it works fine if I use sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar.

I'd suspect you're using sbt-launch-0.11.0, and this is causing sbt to look for a compiled version of sbt that doesn't in fact exist.

Possible fixes are:

1. Just use sbt-launch-0.7.7 for this code.
2. Edit the build.properties file to use a different version of sbt.
3. Get source for sbt-0.7.4, compile with scala 2.9.1 and stash the result in your local ivy repository with the name and location that's being searched.

Options 1 and 2 worked for me.

I haven't done #3 for this, but have done similar things for other code.  It can be a bit painful...

You can have multiple versions of sbt-launch and flip between them depending on the needs of a particular codebase.

Perhaps someone who knows sbt better than I will post a real solution, but I'm hoping this is at least a little helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Update or remove the sbt version(0.7.4) line from [build.properties](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/blob/master/project/build.properties)

Answer (score 0):

That means there's no public version of SBT 0.7.4 compiled against Scala 2.9.1 by the looks of it.