# sbt unresolved dependencies sbt_2.9.1;0.7.4 sbt_2.9.1;0.7.7:

Tags: scala, sbt

I was getting the unresolved dependencies like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994618/how-to-use-scala-time/8721000#8721000).

Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.7.7 ...

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.7.7: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBT 0.7.7 uses Scala 2.7.7 for the project configuration. SBT 0.11 uses Scala 2.9.1. You can use SBT 0.7.7 for configurations up to that version, but versions of SBT newer than 0.7.7 use a non-compatible configuration file.

Note that this is not related to the Scala version that will be used to compile the project itself, just the Scala version that is used to compile the configuration file. These are different things: you can use whatever version of Scala you want to compile your project, but you must use the version of Scala mandated by the SBT version to compile the project configuration.

To get an error message like that you must either have changed the Scala version for the project configuration, or used a newer SBT with a project written for an older version of SBT. Find out which it was, and correct the problem as needed.

I have an SBT 0.7.7 for projects that have not yet migrated to the new version, and the latest SBT for everything else. Put a different name on each script, and you are good to go.

Comment: Daniel, yeh, I know that the source of the problem is that newer SBT has been used in place of the older one, thus, I have said _update_ or _remove_ sbt.version. Feel a bit unfair to get the down vote. I will try to rephrase my answer a bit to be elanorate like yours!. Thanks.

Comment: @user319058 I did not downvote you, and your solution seems good enough. And, of course, if it does solve it for you, then solve it it does.

Comment: Daniel, haha, I don't think that it is you who down vote me nor I am _naming_ anyone in particular. I comment your answer in return of gratitude! btw /elanorate /elaborate

Answer (score 4):

While `sbt-launch.jar` makes an attempt to download and use the version of sbt specified in the project's `project/build.properties`, they must be compiled with matching versions of Scala.  I think sbt 0.7.7 was compiled with Scala 2.7, but the most recent versions of sbt are compiled with Scala 2.9.

Most folks now just use a version of `sbt-launch.jar` that matches the version specified in `project/build.properties`.  If you're running on Linux, OS X, or pretty anything that can run a Bash script, I highly recommend the [launch script](https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt) from [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras).  It will automagically use the version of `sbt-launch.jar` according to what's specified in `project/build.properties`, and gives some other handy command line parameters.

If that doesn't work for you, I think your best bet is different launch scripts to launch the different minor versions of sbt. Such as `sbt7`, `sbt10` and `sbt11`, which launch 0.7.7, 0.10.1 and 0.11.2, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the issue can be resolved by updating or removing the sbt.version entry from project_root_folder/project/build.properties My current sbt version is 0.11.2 and I have updated it to sbt.version=0.11.2 . Removing the entry also works.

Comment: While removing the entry usually works, that's usually not the best solution. Instead it's better to use a launcher that can run the expected version of sbt.