# play -help gives Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.0: missing sbt.xMain

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I created a new app using command `play new hello` and `cd`'ed into the directory. When I type `play` in the directory, I receive the following error:

```
akshay@Akshay:~/play/testn$ play -help
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 43 already retrieved (0kB/45ms)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.0: missing sbt.xMain
```

Play was working fine in my old Ubuntu box. Today only I got a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I know it is error due to change in version, but certainly, I am not able to solve this. Please help me on this.

In checked .sbt/boot/update.log and I can see this :

```
trying http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/jars/oss-parent.jar
                tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/jars/oss-parent.jar
HTTP response status: 404 url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/jars/oss-parent.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.sonatype.oss/oss-parent/7/jars/oss-parent.jar
        typesafe-ivy-releases: resource not reachable for org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.$
         trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same problem , but you may have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505176/unresolved-dependency-sbt-0-13-0-after-update

Comment: thanks, but that didn't help.

Comment: My guess is that your java version does not match your sbt or scala version due to the upgrade. Please add your play, java and scala version to your question. In my case, when I type play, I get: play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_13 and Scala 2.10.0)

Comment: Are you perhaps using Java 8? Could you please give `play -help` a shot with Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

Though error was coming from a fresh ubuntu installation with oracle jdk 8, I tried completely removing jdk and then installing jdk 7, but still no solution. Since it was a fresh installation, I reinstalled ubuntu and installed jdk 7 and problem is solved. Not sure why is it contradictory to Play's recomendation of using Jdk 6 or above. Notifying Play Google Groups about this.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while trying to build using sbt-launcher.jar which was invoked through jenkins. In my case there were two Scala versions within ~/.sbt/boot/ and removing the older version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to setup my development environment for one of our projects when I hit this issue. The problem was the `sbt.version` parameter in the `build.properties` file of our project which specifically mentioned the version of sbt as 0.13.8 and I had sbt 0.13.11.

After removing sbt 0.13.11 and installing 0.13.8, the issue got resolved. Or if it is possible for you to change the sbt version in your `build.properties` file, you can do that as well.