# Unresolved Dependencies in sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt, dependency-management

Running my `sbt` build, I get the following **unresolved dependencies**.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#templates-compiler_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#console_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
parent
 |
  --> sbtApp1
  --> playApp
  --> sbtApp2
  --> project
      --> Build.scala
      --> plugins.sbt
  --> build.sbt
```

My parent/project/plugins.sbt has the following:
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play"    % "sbt-plugin"            % "2.2.0")`

I added the following line to parent/build.sbt, but I'm still getting the compile-time failure.

`libraryDependencies += "play"              % "play_2.10"        % "2.1.0"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this line to `parent/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Voilà. (How did I know? Because the Play 2.2 "Getting Started Guide" says so, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/NewApplication.)

I don't think you need the `libraryDependencies` thing.

Comment: The sad part is that I didn't install play using sbt manually like in that link, but by using activator. Your fix still worked, though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Had a problem with

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.hawtjni#hawtjni-runtime;1.8: configuration not found in org.fusesource.hawtjni#hawtjni-runtime;1.8: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.fusesource.leveldbjni#leveldbjni;1.7 compile
```

On Fedora 22 the solution was as easy as:

```
~]$rm -rf .ivy2/ .sbt/
```

I've seen various answers on the internet telling people to delete the .sbt cache, but the .ivy2/ also causes a problem. If deleting those doesn't fix it, you may also try deleting the .maven2 directory. This forces ivy/gradle/maven to redownload everything. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You mixing up Play 2.1.0 with Play 2.2.0.

Use NOT:

```
libraryDependencies += "play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0"
```

Use:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.10" % "2.2.0"
```

[And be sure, that you have at least one resolver for SBT.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511228/1575096)