# How list all unresolved dependencies in sbt?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

After running `sbt compile` I can long log with error of unresolved dependencies, but can see a list of all unresolved dependencies?

Comment: If you run simply `sbt`, doesn't it lists all the `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` in a formatted table? It has been a while when I last used it but recall such a feature...

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in "[Unresolved Dependencies in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19459377/6309)", or in [Unresolved dependency SBT 0.13.0 after update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18505176/6309), **[running sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Running.html)**  with no command line arguments, meaning starting in interactive mode will print the unresolved dependencies.

For example:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#templates-compiler_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#console_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

[Adding some repo in the ~/.sbt/repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511228/6309) can gelp.